# Etherscan contract not updated even though contract updated

Tags: contract-development, etherscan, contract-upgrading

New to solidity. I updated my contract, but the changes and new functions are not showing in etherscan. is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate? Smart contracts arent upgradeable. Once you deploy something on chain, it's here forever (Well it's an oversimplification, but thats the idea). What did you do exactly when you "updated" your smart contract?